# Java read from json file using Apache Spark specifying the Schema

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have some json file with such format:

```
{"_t":1480647647,"_p":"rattenbt@test.com","_n":"app_loaded","device_type":"desktop"}
{"_t":1480647676,"_p":"rattenbt@test.com","_n":"app_loaded","device_type":"desktop"}
{"_t":1483161958,"_p":"rattenbt@test.com","_n":"app_loaded","device_type":"desktop"}
{"_t":1483162393,"_p":"rattenbt@test.com","_n":"app_loaded","device_type":"desktop"}
{"_t":1483499947,"_p":"rattenbt@test.com","_n":"app_loaded","device_type":"desktop"}
{"_t":1505361824,"_p":"pfitza@test.com","_n":"added_to_team","account":"1234"}
{"_t":1505362047,"_p":"konit@test.com","_n":"added_to_team","account":"1234"}
{"_t":1505362372,"_p":"oechslin@test.com","_n":"added_to_team","account":"1234"}
{"_t":1505362854,"_p":"corrada@test.com","_n":"added_to_team","account":"1234"}
{"_t":1505366071,"_p":"vertigo@test.com","_n":"added_to_team","account":"1234"}
```

I'm using Apache Spark in my java application in order to read this json file and save to parquet format.

If I didn't use schema definition then there is no problem with file parsing
There is my code example:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().json(pathToFile);
dataset.show(100);
```

And there is my console output:

```
+-------------+------------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
|           _n|                _p|        _t|account|channel|device_type|
+-------------+------------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
|   app_loaded| rattenbt@test.com|1480647647|   null|   null|    desktop|
|   app_loaded| rattenbt@test.com|1480647676|   null|   null|    desktop|
|   app_loaded| rattenbt@test.com|1483161958|   null|   null|    desktop|
|   app_loaded| rattenbt@test.com|1483162393|   null|   null|    desktop|
|   app_loaded| rattenbt@test.com|1483499947|   null|   null|    desktop|
|added_to_team|   pfitza@test.com|1505361824|   1234|   null|       null|
|added_to_team|    konit@test.com|1505362047|   1234|   null|       null|
...
```

When I'm using schema definition like this

```
StructType schema = new StructType();
schema.add("_n", StringType, true);
schema.add("_p", StringType, true);
schema.add("_t", TimestampType, true);
schema.add("account", StringType, true);
schema.add("channel", StringType, true);
schema.add("device_type", StringType, true);
// Read data from file
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().schema(schema).json(pathToFile);
dataset.show(100);
```

I got console output :

```
++
||
++
||
||
||
||
...
```

What's wrong with schma definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StrutType` is immutable, so just discard all additions. If you print it

```
schema.printTreeString
```

you'll see it doesn't contain any field:

```
root
```

You should use:

```
StructType schema = new StructType()
  .add("_n", StringType, true)
  .add("_p", StringType, true)
  .add("_t", TimestampType, true)
  .add("account", StringType, true)
  .add("channel", StringType, true)
  .add("device_type", StringType, true);
```